# I'm having trouble applying a js file inside my django template

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I'm learning the thing with Django and I'm trying to adapt a bootstrap template for the index page

I have it as follows

At home.html

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
This is a starter template page. Use this page to start your new project from
scratch. This page gets rid of all links and provides the needed markup only.
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
 
  

  <title>{{title}}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'lib/AdminLTE-3.2.0/plugins/fontawesome-free-6.4.0/css/all.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'lib/AdminLTE-3.2.0/css/adminlte.min.css' %}">
  <script src="{% static 'lib/AdminLTE-3.2.0/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  
  <script src="{% static 'lib/AdminLTE-3.2.0/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/AdminLTE-3.2.0/js/adminlte.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/sweetalert2-9.10.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/functions.js' %}"></script>


  
  {% block head %}
  
  {% endblock %}
</head>


{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
</html>
```

In index.html

```html
{% extends 'home.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block head %}
    
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'homepage/images/favicon.png' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/plugins/themefisher-font/style.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/plugins/lightbox2/css/lightbox.min.css' %}">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/plugins/animate/animate.css' %}">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/plugins/slick/slick.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/css/style.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>  
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/parallax/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js' %}"></script>  
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/lightbox2/js/lightbox.min.js' %}"></script>  
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/slick/slick.min.js' %}"></script>  
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/filterizr/jquery.filterizr.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/smooth-scroll/smooth-scroll.min.js' %}"></script>  
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCcABaamniA6OL5YvYSpB3pFMNrXwXnLwU"></script>
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/google-map/gmap.js' %}"></script>  
<script src="{% static 'homepage/js/script.js' %}"></script>


{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<body id="body">


  <div id="preloader">
    <div class='preloader'>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>


{% include 'header.html' %}

{% include 'principal.html' %}


<section class="service-2 section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <!-- section title -->
        <div class="title text-center">
          <h2>What Do We Offer</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Voluptates, earum. </p>
          <div class="border"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /section title -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 text-center d-none d-md-block">
        <img loading="lazy" src="{% static 'homepage/images/about/member.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid inline-block" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="service-item">
              <i class="tf-ion-ios-alarm-outline"></i>
              <h4>Time Management</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae risus nec dui venenatis.</p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- END COL -->
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="service-item">
              <i class="tf-ion-ios-briefcase-outline"></i>
              <h4>Marketing Ideas</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae risus nec dui venenatis.</p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- END COL -->
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="service-item">
              <i class="tf-ion-ios-email-outline"></i>
              <h4>Mail Support</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae risus nec dui venenatis.</p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- END COL -->
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="service-item">
              <i class="tf-ion-ios-locked-outline"></i>
              <h4>Secure System</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae risus nec dui venenatis.</p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- END COL -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- End row -->
  </div> <!-- End container -->
</section> <!-- End section -->

<!--
Start About Section
==================================== -->
<section class="about-2 section" id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <!-- section title -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="title text-center">
                    <h2>We Are Bingo Agency</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam reprehenderit accusamus labore iusto,
                        aut, eum itaque illo totam tempora eius.</p>
                    <div class="border"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /section title -->
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                <img loading="lazy" src="{% static 'homepage/images/about/about-2.png' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul class="checklist">
                    <li>Donec sed odio dui. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem laca quam venenatis vestibulum.</li>
                    <li>Aenean quam. Pellentesque ornare sem laca quam venenatis vestibulum.</li>
                    <li>Donec sed odio dui. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem laca quam venenatis vestibulum.</li>
                    <li>Etiam porta sem multipage evint landing magna mollis euismod a pharetra augue.</li>
                    <li>Aenean quam. Pellentesque ornare sem laca quam venenatis vestibulum.</li>
                </ul>
                <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-main mt-20">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- End row -->
    </div> <!-- End container -->
</section> <!-- End section -->

<!--
Start Call To Action
==================================== -->
<section class="call-to-action section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-8 text-center">
                <h2>Let's Create Something Together</h2>
                <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicudin bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum,
                    nesagittis sem nid elit. Duis sed odio sitain elit.</p>
                <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-main">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- End row -->
    </div> <!-- End container -->
</section> <!-- End section -->

<!--
Start Counter Section
==================================== -->
<section class="counter-wrapper section-sm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-8 text-center">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2>Award-Winning Agency</h2>
                    <p>Vestibulum nisl tortor, consectetur quis imperdiet bibendum, laoreet sed arcu. Sed condimentum iaculis ex, in faucibus lorem accumsan non. Donec mattis tincidunt metus. Morbi sed tortor a risus luctus dignissim.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- first count item -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center ">
                <div class="counters-item">
                    <i class="tf-ion-ios-alarm-outline"></i>
                    <div>
                        <span class="counter" data-count="150">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Happy Clients</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end first count item -->

            <!-- second count item -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center ">
                <div class="counters-item">
                    <i class="tf-ion-ios-analytics-outline"></i>
                    <div>
                        <span class="counter" data-count="130">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Projects completed</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end second count item -->

            <!-- third count item -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center ">
                <div class="counters-item">
                    <i class="tf-ion-ios-compose-outline"></i>
                    <div>
                        <span class="counter" data-count="99">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Positive feedback</h3>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end third count item -->

            <!-- fourth count item -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center ">
                <div class="counters-item kill-border">
                    <i class="tf-ion-ios-bolt-outline"></i>
                    <div>
                        <span class="counter" data-count="250">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Cups of Coffee</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end fourth count item -->
        </div> <!-- end row -->
    </div> <!-- end container -->
</section> <!-- end section -->


{% include 'testimonial.html' %}
{% include 'blog.html' %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}


</body>

{% endblock %}
```

in testimonial.html

```html
{% load static %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock %}
<section class="testimonial section" id="testimonial">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">               
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <!-- testimonial wrapper -->
                <div class="testimonial-slider">
                    <!-- testimonial single -->
                    <div class="item text-center">
                        <i class="tf-ion-chatbubbles"></i>
                        <!-- client info -->
                        <div class="client-details">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum nulla, soluta dolorum. Eos earum, magni asperiores, unde corporis labore, enim, voluptatum officiis voluptates alias natus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, officia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, quia?</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /client info -->
                        <!-- client photo -->
                        <div class="client-thumb">
                            <img loading="lazy" src="{% static 'homepage/images/client-logo/clients-1.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-meta">
                            <h3>William Martin</h3>
                            <span>CEO , Company Name</span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /client photo -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /testimonial single -->
            
                    <!-- testimonial single -->
                    <div class="item text-center">
                        <i class="tf-ion-chatbubbles"></i>
                        <!-- client info -->
                        <div class="client-details">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum nulla, soluta dolorum. Eos earum, magni asperiores, unde corporis labore, enim, voluptatum officiis voluptates alias natus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, officia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, quia?</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /client info -->
                        <!-- client photo -->
                        <div class="client-thumb">
                            <img loading="lazy" src="{% static 'homepage/images/client-logo/clients-2.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-meta">
                            <h3>Emma Harrison</h3>
                            <span>CEO , Company Name</span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /client photo -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /testimonial single -->
                
                    <!-- testimonial single -->
                    <div class="item text-center">
                        <i class="tf-ion-chatbubbles"></i>
                        <!-- client info -->
                        <div class="client-details">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum nulla, soluta dolorum. Eos earum, magni asperiores, unde corporis labore, enim, voluptatum officiis voluptates alias natus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, officia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, quia?</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /client info -->
                        <!-- client photo -->
                        <div class="client-thumb">
                            <img loading="lazy" src="{% static 'homepage/images/client-logo/clients-3.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-meta">
                            <h3>Alexander Lucas</h3>
                            <span>CEO , Company Name</span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /client photo -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /testimonial single -->
                </div>
            </div>      <!-- end col lg 12 -->
        </div>      <!-- End row -->
    </div>       <!-- End container -->
</section>    <!-- End Section -->
```

I am trying to section, clean and customize step by step the index template.html but the problem is in a function that I have inside a 'homepage/js/script.js'  file

```html
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  /* ========================================================================= */
  /*    Page Preloader
  /* ========================================================================= */
  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });


  // navbarDropdown
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $('#navigation .dropdown-toggle').on('click', function () {
            $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').animate({
                height: 'toggle'
            }, 300);
        });
  }
  
  //Hero Slider
  $('.hero-slider').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    infinite: true,
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: '<button type=\'button\' class=\'prevArrow\'></button>',
    nextArrow: '<button type=\'button\' class=\'nextArrow\'></button>',
    dots: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 7000,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
    pauseOnHover: false
  });

/*BELOW IS THE PROBLEM!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
 $('.testimonial-slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000
  });

  $('.hero-slider').slickAnimation();

  /* ========================================================================= */
  /*    Portfolio Filtering Hook
  /* =========================================================================  */
  // filter
  setTimeout(function(){
    var containerEl = document.querySelector('.filtr-container');
    var filterizd;
    if (containerEl) {
      filterizd = $('.filtr-container').filterizr({});
    }
  }, 500);

  /* ========================================================================= */
  /*    Testimonial Carousel
  /* =========================================================================  */
  //Init the slider



  /* ========================================================================= */
  /*    Clients Slider Carousel
  /* =========================================================================  */
  //Init the slider
  $('.clients-logo-slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        dots: false
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false
      }
    }
    ]
  });

  /* ========================================================================= */
  /*    Company Slider Carousel
  /* =========================================================================  */
  $('.company-gallery').slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        dots: false
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 667,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false
      }
    }
    ]
  });

  /* ========================================================================= */
  /*    On scroll fade/bounce effect
  /* ========================================================================= */
  var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]');

  // -----------------------------
  //  Count Up
  // -----------------------------
  function counter() {
    var oTop;
    if ($('.counter').length !== 0) {
      oTop = $('.counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
      $('.counter').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
          countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
        $({
          countNum: $this.text()
        }).animate({
          countNum: countTo
        }, {
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function () {
            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
          },
          complete: function () {
            $this.text(this.countNum);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
  // -----------------------------
  //  On Scroll
  // -----------------------------
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    counter();

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 50) {
      $('.navigation').addClass('sticky-header');
    } else {
      $('.navigation').removeClass('sticky-header');
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

In the marked marker, that js function of .testimonial-slider is not executed

On the other hand, if I place that function within testimonial.html if it works for me, I do not understand why.

I appreciate your help, I am new to Django and was not familiar with javascript.

Comment: The phrase `.testimonial-slider` does not occur in that JS file.

Comment: Sorry, I had copied the code wrong, in my js file there is that piece of code

Comment: You are not calling `$('.testimonial-slider').slickAnimation();`.

Comment: I have made the correction in the question and added this in script.js   
   $('.testimonial-slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000
  });

Comment: I know, but you STILL haven't called `slickAnimation` on it.

Comment: I did and I still have the same problem, I suspect I must have something with JQuery, because when I put the full function of '.testimonial-slider' inside testimonial.html it works, but why doesn't it work inside the js file?

Comment: Where are you loading the JS file?  You don't have that code inside a `$(document).ready` handler, so it's going to run just as soon as it is encountered, so if you load the JS before the HTML, the HTML won't exist yet.

Comment: I think I'm calling it in index.html

<script src="{% static 'homepage/js/script.js' %}"></script>   ----> this is it                                     
 I think that function that you say of $(document).ready is the same (function ($) right?

Comment: No!  All that does is make the `jquery` object available as the name `$` within the function. The code is executed at once.  What you are thinking of is `$(function() { ... })`, which is the jquery shortcut for `$(document).ready`.  Looks similar, but behaves very differently.

Comment: So what should I modify and how exactly? should i add $(document).ready before the function $('.testimonial-slider').slickAnimation();?

Comment: Well, only part of that function needs to wait, but if it were me, I would replace your very first line with `$(function() {` and the very last line with `})`.  Your `$(window)` methods could be separate, but it won't hurt.

Comment: I moved the function $('.testimonial-slider').slick({ under the preloader function and it worked, thanks